# When does Professor X lose his ability to walk?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, paradox

At the end of the X-Men first class movie, magneto deflects a bullet causing it to render professor X - who was a boy at the time - to become paralyzed in his legs. However in The last stand when Charles and magneto recruit Jean Grey we can clearly see that he's walking!

Comment: The X-Men franchise hates continuity almost as much as Star Trek.

Comment: true but i hoped that there would be a logical answer :-)